# Access a class object instantiated in one code behind page, in different code behind pages in .net

Tags: .net, sql-server, class, object, code-behind

I am bulding an application that has multiple pages. The first aspx page has user selection options which are mostly radio buttons and dropdown menus. The second page has another category of user selection options and so on till 4th page. At that point of time when user clicks submit button on 4th aspx page all the selections should be stored in a sql table.

I have a class(non-static) with properties to store all the user selections. My question is how can a access the class object which is instantiated in code behind for page1, in code behind for other pages so that I can store all selections in properties of that object and store values of these properies in SQL in 4th page.
I cannot use sessions because there will be 100s of users and could crash my application. Also i want to store all the selections at a time in SQL to reduce multiple SQL calls.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create the record with the first page and update it the record with each other page, storing the record id in session?

Page 1

Insert the record in the database with the questions from page1 and null for the others. Retrieve the record id of the inserted record and store it in session.

Page 2

Update the record in the database with the questions from page2, using the id in session

Page n

repeat

This also gives you the option of allowing the user to return and pickup where they left off. As a side note I'd probably create the record before the user even answers any questions, that way they could safely use the back button to page 1 and change their answers.

Comment: I didn't understand your first suggestions. Can you please explain a little bit. They have to be different pages as I need to show a sitemappath so I cannot use user controls.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use the Session, you might want to store the selection of each page in a cookie. This could be done client-side (using javascript).

On the last page, you instantiate your class and set its properties from the different cookies.

Comment: Sorry I cant use javascript as I need to support people with javascript and cookies disabled on their browser.

Comment: @user648610: I assumed you were using ASP.NET (which obviously is not the case as that needs javascript?)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET does support cross page postbacks which allow you to post page 1 back to page 2 and access the controls from the first page in the code behind of the second page. You can find some more information on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx. It'll take a bit of hacking about to get it to work over four pages and it won't be terribly pretty but it should be possible.

I know you want to reduce SQL calls but personally I'd probably look at adding some sort of holding table into my database and adding data into that table as the user move through the four pages of your form.

For example say page one has a field called first name, page two has a field called last name and page three has a field called date of birth. I'd create a database table with an ID, first name, last name and date of birth column. When the user finishes page one I would create a row in that table and save the first name into it. How you manage the ID's in the database is up to you but I would then grab the ID and hold it in session state or an anonymous user profile using the ASP.NET profile provider.

When the user has finished page two I would grab the ID back from the session, or wherever I've stored it, and do an update on that row in the database saving the second name and so on. When it gets to the final stage you can pull everything saved so far back from the database and run it through any business logic you need to.

After all is said and done you can remove the data from that holding table as it should now be stored elsewhere in its final state. If you do go down this road it's a good idea to remove partially completed data every so often. It's probably a safe bet that if someone filled in page 1 three hours ago they aren't coming back to finish the rest.